# How to make a formula occur in a cell if it meets certain condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have code as below, but it does nothing. It is supposed to give
`=IF($G$12="adhoc","A"&C8&G14&C19,"")` in cell c6 if cell g12 is "adhoc".

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
  ByVal Target As Range)

    ' See if the change is related to our cell
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("G12")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        If Range("G12") = "adhoc" Then
            Worksheet("data").Range("C6").Formula = "=IF($G$12=""adhoc"",""A""&C8&G14&C19,"""")"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Just checking - you do mean to use the Workbook SheetChange event, as opposed to the Worksheet.Change event?

Comment: Nothing Is happening, its supposed to give formula in cell c6 if cell G12 have word adhoc. But nothing is happening.

Comment: Please confirm that the above code is in ThisWorkbook module.

Comment: @scott craner: basically what I want to do is, if my cell G12 contains the word "adhoc", then cell c6 should use the formula "=IF($G$12="adhoc","A"&C8&G14&C19,"")", else it should be kept blank

Comment: Make sure to qualify your ranges since you're working with multiple worksheets

Comment: @Vincent G no I was not using it in the ThisWorkbook module, now I have corrected it. so it seems to be calling the macro, but now its showing error on line Worksheet("data").Range("C6").Formula = "=IF($G$12=""adhoc"",""A""&C8&G14&C19

Comment: Where is this code located?  do you want the changes to happen on all sheets?  Why the formula why not just put the value you want in the cell?  The change event will fire each time.  Why not just put the formula yourself in the cell?  It will do what you want.  Once the code puts the formula in the cell it will always be there, you never clear it, so I do not understand the need for the code.

Comment: @ScottCraner No I want this because cell g12 value may change, and the if formula should work only if g12 text is "adhoc".

Comment: The point is that C6 won't show anything if G12 doesn't equal "adhoc".

Comment: But your formula already is an IF, you are doing the IF twice.  So lets say there is nothing in C6 it is blank.  The user adds `Adhoc` to G12.  The code runs, puts the formula in place, And the value shows because the formula returns the true portion of the formula.  The user change G12, the code runs but becuase it no longer is `Adhoc` it does nothing, there is not Else in your if, the formula remains in the cell.  The formula itself returns the false portion `""`.  It is the formula that blanks the cell not the code.  The formula never would be removed and the formula does what you want.

Comment: So why the code?  It only places the formula in the cell the first time `Adhoc` is used and then the formula does all the work without the need of the code.  And you are using comp time to do nothing the formula is not already doing by running code that at best will put the exact formula in the exact same cell which would return the exact response whether you ran the code or not.

Answer (score -1):

The first error I got when running your code was because `Worksheet("data").Range("C6").Formula` needs to be `Worksheets("data").Range("C6").Formula` - it was missing the 's' in 'Worksheets'.

After fixing that, I assume the code is actually in the workbook module, as the event name indicates.

It runs fine, as long as the target is on the sheet which changed and the target includes cell G12; however if the active sheet is not 'data' it will error again because as soon as the formula is updated on the 'data' tab that triggers the event. The subsequent event will cause a secondary error because the target is not on the same worksheet as the range you are trying to intersect it with: `Intersect(Target, Range("G12"))`. Target is on sheet 'data' and `Range("G12")` is on `Activesheet`.

If you only want this to run when the active sheet is 'data' then you need to put this in `Worksheet_Change` in the 'data' code module, not as a workbook event.

If you want this to run when there is a change on *any* sheet, then you'll need to update the logic around the intersect by fully qualifying the range reference in `Intersect(Target, Range("G12"))` - for example: `Intersect(Target, sh.Range("G12"))`

To address the its *not doing anything* comment, it may be due to the fact that it only fires if the change was actually in cell G12. If you are changing values in any other cell, the code runs, but the `if not intersect() is nothing` prevents the cell formula update that you are expecting.

Working code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
  ByVal Target As Range)

    ' See if the change is related to our cell
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, sh.Range("G12")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        If Range("G12") = "adhoc" Then
            Worksheets("data").Range("C6").Formula = "=IF($G$12=""adhoc"",""A""&C8&G14&C19,"""")"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: FWI, in this instance `Target.Parent` is the same worksheet as `Sh`